# sct-dot fails on updated simple-call-tree

Tags: libraries

`sct-dot` is convenient for visualizing relationships by graphviz(dot) among functions in programs.

- [EmacsWiki: Simple Call Tree](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SimpleCallTree)

Unfortunately, since `simple-call-tree` has updated from 20150806.1133 to 20151116.802 on melpa, `sct-dot` does not work.

Are the any work arounds?

Comment: Did you consider contacting the author of the library for a bug report?  Ideally with something more informative than "does not work".

Comment: You're right, thanks for your comment, I'll try to get more information on simple-call-tree, and more productive.